# Hibernate- cascading option for one to many using spring HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my application, I'm having a one-to-many relationship in which I have the following requirements. As an example, take Car- Owner relationship. Owner can have multiple cars, while one car can have one owner only.

- When I save parent entity (Owner) with car as a collection in it, I want the car to get inserted automatically. Same for update as well.
- When remove some car objects from the collection & save, I want the  removed car objects to get deleted from the database.

I tried with following options in the hibernate xml mapping:

```
inverse="false" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
```

And I inserted using

```
HibernateTemplate.persist()
```

Updated using

```
HibernateTemplate.merge()
```

The update works well, but the insert is not working properly.

Can anybody advice me what is the exact cascade option & the method to use in saving & updating such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

See 21.3. Cascading life cycle here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It clearly describes that the cascade option needs to be all-delete-orphan. But When I remove one element from the list & update the parent, it is not deleting the child:

Comment: From code:

user.setCars(cars);
session.update(user);
where the user is having a new list of Car objects. Pls correct me.